# github actions curl for github api fails with curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Tags: curl, github-actions, github-api

I am trying to get all the tags in a repo using GITHUB API curl method from github actions(runs on ubuntu)  and I get below error. I used \ to escape quotes and : still having same issue

```
      curl \                                
        -H \"Accept\: application/vnd.github+json\" \   
        -H \"Authorization\: Bearer TOKEN\" \
        \"https\://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/tags\"
```

error:

curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be related to the syntax you used to make the call.

I just tested the service using this workflow implementation in a POC repository, following the [GitHub API documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#list-repository-tags):

```
on:
  push:

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          curl \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
            https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/tags
        env:
          TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

And it worked as expected with this [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester65.yml), if you want to check the output [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/3289340242/jobs/5420749708).

Comment: It worked ! do you know how to get only get tags RN in using the curl and then doing | grep name writing to a file and using if to check tag exist. Thanks !

Comment: In that case, it would probably be easier to achieve this by using a git command in the workflow after checking out the repository. This command line for example return all the tags from the repository: `git tag -l --sort=-version:refname`, you could then write the output in a file to perform what you need to do.